# Personal fixed path on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I'd like to create a application for android that navigate the users over a road between a point A and a towards a point B.

I don't want google to calculate the most efficent path to reach the point B from the point A but I want to be able to choose the path that I want between this 2 points.

I took a look at the API's in the official documentation of google maps but I didn't saw anything about it, someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own path you can use **Polylines**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

Comment: I can use polylines for mark areas on the map, but can I use them even for navigate a very specific road?

Comment: No, you can't. I guess you want that the polyline follow the road, I am doing an App with a similar requirement and I dind't find a practical way to do it. I use this library but I had to change some parts to make a good polyline. https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary